# Google Apps Script - Gmail - Error Handling When No Message/Thread

Tags: google-apps-script

Hoping someone can help me out with handling 'errors' in my script when there is no message/thread found. I thought I had done that with the IF statement based on message.lengh but its not working and still errors when no email is found matching the inputted search criteria (e). It works perfectly every time a message IS found.

Many thanks.
Moz

```
function ImportCDWFiles(e){
  
  var Threads = GmailApp.search(e,0,1); 
  var Message = Threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var Attachment = Message.getAttachments()[0];
  if (Threads.length >0){

  Logger.log(Threads.length);
  Logger.log(Attachment.getName())
  var SourceFile = Folder.createFile(Attachment.copyBlob())
  var SourceID = SourceFile.getId();
  var XlsxBlob = Attachment[0]; // 
  var ConvertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, SourceFile).id;  //XlsxBlob
  Logger.log("Converted File ID= "+ ConvertedSpreadsheetId)
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ConvertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0]; // There is the data in 1st tab.
  var Data = Sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  //var Data = Sheet.getDataRange().offset(headerRowNumber, 0, sheet.getLastRow() - headerRowNumber).getValues();
    

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetIDHere').getSheetByName('SheetName');
  var range = sheet.getRange(LastRow+1, 1, Data.length, Data[0].length);

  range.setValues(Data);

  Drive.Files.remove(ConvertedSpreadsheetId); // Remove the converted file.
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- At `var Message = Threads[0].getMessages()[0]`, when the length of `Threads` is `0`, an error occurs.
- If the attachment files are not included, an error occurs.
- In your script, `Folder` and `LastRow` are not declared.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function ImportCDWFiles(e) {
  var Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("###"); // Please set your folder ID.

  var Threads = GmailApp.search(e, 0, 1);
  if (Threads.length == 0) return;
  var Message = Threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var Attachment = Message.getAttachments();
  if (Attachment.length == 0) return;
  Attachment = Attachment[0];
  Logger.log(Attachment.getName())
  var SourceFile = Folder.createFile(Attachment.copyBlob());
  var ConvertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({ mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS }, SourceFile).id;
  Logger.log("Converted File ID= " + ConvertedSpreadsheetId);
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ConvertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0];
  var LastRow = Sheet.getLastRow();
  var Data = Sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###').getSheetByName('###'); // Please set your values.
  var range = sheet.getRange(LastRow + 1, 1, Data.length, Data[0].length);
  range.setValues(Data);
  Drive.Files.remove(ConvertedSpreadsheetId);
}
```

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot know the mimeType of the attachment file. So, I couldn't implement checking the mimeType of the attachment file. If you can know, when this check is implemented, the error related to the mimeType might be able to be avoided.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike; that fixed it and i've learned something along the way which is even better.   The other variables were declared as constants further up - i should have added that.

Comment: @Morris Coyle Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.